# React 16 read state issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    const [streaming, setStreaming] = useState(false);
    
    const turnStreamingOn = () => {
        setStreaming(true);
        process();
    }
    
    const process = () => {
        console.log('streaming:', streaming);
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                turnStreamingOn();
            }}>{streaming ? 'streaming' : 'not streaming'}</button>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Test;
```

on button click, we have 'streaming' in UI, but console.log in 'process' function says it's false. What am I doing wrong? How to read the state properly?

Comment: State changes are asynchronous, so you can't change it then `console.log` straight after. Print the state in the *body* of the function, you'll see the latest state value

Comment: I think `process` function is called before `setStreaming` finishes updating the state. This is a problem when using hooks unlike in class components where `this.setState({}, callback)` accepts callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    const [streaming, setStreaming] = useState(false);
    
    const turnStreamingOn = () => {
        setStreaming(true);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('streaming: ', streaming)
    }, [streaming])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                turnStreamingOn();
            }}>{streaming ? 'streaming' : 'not streaming'}</button>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Test;
```

You should use `useEffect` for this purpose.